# Got the error "Build optimization failed: found page without a React Component as default export in pages/" Help me

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In developer mode worked great. Later in CMD, I sent "npm run build. Got error...

```
info  - Checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully

> Build optimization failed: found pages without a React Component as default export in
pages/js/TimeClock
pages/js/ChangePage
```

I tried to fix it. Nothing on the internet helped. Here are my files:

**index.js**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Time from './js/TimeClock.page';
import { ChangePage0, ChangePage1, ChangePage2 } from './js/ChangePage.page';

export default function Home() {
  ...
}
```

**TimeClock.page.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export function tick()
{
    const site = (
        <div>
            <span className="time">
                {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}
            </span>
        </div>
    );
    ReactDOM.render(site, document.getElementById('time'));
}
setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

**next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = {
  pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js'], nextConfig
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understrand what you're trying to do with the setIinterval on a component but you probably need to export default instead of a naming export.

In TimeClock.page.js

```
function Tick() {
   ...
}

export default Tick;
```